# Why is a Custom Container closure not allowing different views?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on a Custom Container, but I get an error:

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report

with the following code (error location is at the bottom of the code below):

```
struct ZoomCardView<Content: View>: View {
    let contentDefault: ((Binding<Bool>)) -> Content
    let contentZoomed: (Binding<Bool>) -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder defaultContent: @escaping (Binding<Bool>) -> Content, @ViewBuilder zoomed: @escaping (Binding<Bool>) -> Content) {
        self.contentDefault = defaultContent
        self.contentZoomed = zoomed
    }
    
    @State private var isShowing: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if isShowing {
                self.contentZoomed($isShowing)
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 0, anchor: .center))
            } else {
                self.contentDefault($isShowing)
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 0, anchor: .center))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DefaultView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Default")
        }
    }
}

struct ZoomView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Zoom")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {   <----------- *** Error
        ZoomCardView { isShowing in
            DefaultView()
        } zoomed: { isShowing in
            ZoomView()
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

I noticed that in `ContentView_Previews`, if I pass the same view, the error disappears. For example:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ZoomCardView { isShowing in
            ZoomView()
        } zoomed: { isShowing in
            ZoomView()
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

Why can't I pass different views when `ZoomCardView` expects a parameter of type `<Content: View>`? What I would like to do is to eventually specify a `View`, or any of the stack types (i.e. `ZStack`, `VStack` or `HStack`), giving the callsite ultimate control as to what gets to be shown. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two generic parameters if you want to pass two *different* views.

Instead of:

```
struct ZoomCardView<Content: View>: View
```

use:

```
struct ZoomCardView<ContentDefault, ContentZoomed>: View where ContentDefault: View, ContentZoomed: View
```

Full example:

```
struct ZoomCardView<ContentDefault, ContentZoomed>: View where ContentDefault: View, ContentZoomed: View {
    let contentDefault: ((Binding<Bool>)) -> ContentDefault
    let contentZoomed: (Binding<Bool>) -> ContentZoomed
    
    init(
        @ViewBuilder defaultContent: @escaping (Binding<Bool>) -> ContentDefault,
        @ViewBuilder zoomed: @escaping (Binding<Bool>) -> ContentZoomed
    ) {
        self.contentDefault = defaultContent
        self.contentZoomed = zoomed
    }
    
    @State private var isShowing: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if isShowing {
                self.contentZoomed($isShowing)
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 0, anchor: .center))
            } else {
                self.contentDefault($isShowing)
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 0, anchor: .center))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pawello2222! Works great. TBH, I'm still confused as to why this is needed. If the views are of type `View` and ZoomCardView was defined as `<Content: View>: View`, why does the compiler make a distinction? I'm very curious about this. Thanks again!

Comment: @titusmagnus If you take a look at init, it expects two closures, both with the same return type (Content). This way you can only pass the same type to both closures. And DefaultView and ZoomView have different types. Creating a second generic type allows you to put two different types to these closures.

Comment: It does make sense, but I guess what throws me off is that since *both* of them are a `View` and `init` requires `Content` of type `View`, then even if both views are of a different type, they're still of type `View`. Do you see where my confusion lies? Thanks again!

Comment: @titusmagnus, I noticed that in your previous question too. `Content` is defined as a generic type that represent some kind of view - the *specific* kind is defined by how your init is invoked (e.g. could be `Text`, or `VStack<Text>`, whatever it is). But you need two different views - each is a different type - in init, so you need two generic types to represent that

Comment: @titusmagnus But you can't use the `View` as a constraint as it's a protocol with an *associatedtype*. I suggest you read [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) and [Opaque Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html)